# Detect sequence of 4 spaces at end of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

What would be the best method for detecting a sequence of 4 spaces at the very end of the first line of an `NSString`?

```
NSString *testString = @"Something    \nblah blah blah\nmore stuff here";
NSString *firstLine = [[testString componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSRange range = [firstLine rangeOfString:@"    " options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
BOOL found = range.location != NSNotFound;
```

This almost does the trick, but how would I make sure that this sequence of four spaces is at the very end of my string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the method `- (BOOL)hasSuffix:(NSString *)aString`.

```
if ([myString hasSuffix:@"    "]) {
    NSLog(@"myString had the suffix!");
}
```

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/hasSuffix%3a) states that this is a convenience for `NSAnchoredSearch | NSBackwardsSearch`, so you could also express this as:

```
if (NSNotFound != [myString rangeOfString:@"    " options:NSAnchoredSearch | NSBackwardsSearch].location) {
    NSLog(@"myString had the suffix!");
}
```

But that's clearly not as expressive.

Comment: ohhhh. that's brilliant!